# Build a plotly scatterplot of multiple subplots with two drop down buttons one for x and one for y axis

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create a plot of multiple subplots where I could change all the subplot x and y axis with just one two buttons (one for all x axis and one for all y axis). The problem with my current code seems to be that all the subplots plot only the values of the last "stage". I want each plot to be plotting only values from one stage, meaning plot 1 plots only values from stage 1 and plot 2 from stage 2 and so on...
I've been working on this for quite some time and can't really find a solution. Any help or hint would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
        df = self.stage_values
        stage_values = df["stage"].unique()

        # Calculate the number of rows needed
        n_rows = int(numpy.ceil(len(stage_values) / 3.0))

        # Create subplot titles
        titles = [f"Stage: {stage_value}" for stage_value in stage_values]

        # Create subplots
        fig = sp.make_subplots(rows=n_rows, cols=3, subplot_titles=titles)

        for i in range(len(stage_values)):
            row = i // 3 + 1
            col = i % 3 + 1

            # Get the stage value for this index
            stage_value = stage_values[i]

            # Subset the data for this stage value
            subset = df[df["stage"] == stage_value]

            variables = [value for value in subset if
                         value not in ["stage", "nrt", "scan"]]

            # Create scatter plot for each variable
            for var in variables:
                fig.add_trace(
                    go.Scatter(
                        x=subset[var],
                        y=subset[var],
                        hovertemplate='x: %{x} <br>y: %{y}',
                        mode="markers",
                        name=var
                    ),
                    row=row,
                    col=col
                )


            # Add dropdown menus for x and y axes
            fig.update_layout(
                updatemenus=[
                    dict(
                        buttons=list([
                            dict(
                                args=["x", [subset[var]]],
                                label=f'x = {var}',
                                method="restyle",
                            ) for var in variables
                        ]),
                        direction="down",
                        pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
                        showactive=True,
                        x=0.1,
                        xanchor="left",
                        y=1.1,
                        yanchor="top"
                    ),
                    dict(
                        buttons=list([
                            dict(
                                args=["y", [subset[var]]],
                                label=f'y = {var}',
                                method="restyle"
                            ) for var in variables
                        ]),
                        direction="down",
                        pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
                        showactive=True,
                        x=0.2,
                        xanchor="left",
                        y=1.1,
                        yanchor="top"
                    )
                ]
            )



        fig.show()
```

I am trying to be change the x and y axis of all the subplots at the same time while also plotting different values for each subplot.